# Grafana heatmap: hide y-axis labels

Tags: label, heatmap, grafana

I am creating a heatmap from 201 data fields coming from an Influx-DB. Currently, the result looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to hide the y-axis tick-labels in this visualization? In the JSON I set `show` to false:

```
 "yAxis": {
    "decimals": null,
    "format": "short",
    "logBase": 1,
    "max": null,
    "min": null,
    "show": false,
    "splitFactor": null
  },
```

But this does not have the desired effect. If possible, I would like to switch off the grid lines too...

Comment: As I do not get any answer here, I posted this as feature request for GRAFANA: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/25097

Answer (score -1):

You can hide the Y-Axis Labels using the ***Alias by*** JSON field , writing a space into that field.

```
  "targets": [
    {
      "alias": "",
```

[default Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/la92v.jpg)

```
  "targets": [
    {
      "alias": " ",
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3zfF.jpg)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)